# Retrieving only reactivated projects from a history of updates

Tags: sql

So I have a table that tracks the updating of a projects status. Now each time a project changes status a record of it is inserted into a new row. This table in its simplified form looks like this:

```
+-----------+------------+--------+
| ProjectID | UpdateDate | Status |
+-----------+------------+--------+
|           |            |        |
|           |            |        |
|           |            |        |
+-----------+------------+--------+
```

The possible values for the `Status` column are either:

- Reactivated
- Closed
- Pending
- Active

Now here is where it gets tricky for me at least. I want to be able to select only currently reactivated projects. This logically means that a project that has an existing row with Reactivated as its status but **not having the most recent record for that ID as a closed status**. Thanks for any help on this I am having a hard time visualizing the SQL query for this.

**BONUS** (for me)

If you could write the query as a create stored procedure that would be awesome.

**UPDATE**

Bolded the requirements of being reactivated.

**UPDATED UPDATE**

Some test data

```
ProjectID | UpdateDate   |  Status  
-----------------------------------
3566      | 2011-11-09   |  Pending 
1282      | 2011-11-17   |  Reactivated 
3351      | 2011-11-17   |  Closed  
2252      | 2011-11-17   |  Reactivated 
2252      | 2011-11-17   |  Active
```

Now with this query it should show id's 1282 and 2252 because they both have reactivated in a row and do not have closed as their last updated status.

Comment: This is a poor model, especially because project ID isn't a primary key. The database should be redesigned into a history stored in a separate table. Then this query wouldn't be as bad, and you'd get a lot better performance

Comment: I know but its an addon to an existing legacy database that has been maintained by many many people. Also there is a primary key of history id I left that out because that is irrelevant. But then again if you dont want to use the date updated then I guess you could use the id instead but that is less descriptive to the actual problem

Comment: I liked the "BONUS (for me)" part... At least OP is being honest about just wanting us to do his work...

Comment: Ah, the historyId is not irrelevant. It might make some queries simpler.

Comment: yes but the updated date means teh date in which it was updated and not the time it was inserted so possibly it would not coincide correctly as the most recent update

Comment: So you want something that is not currently "closed" but has ever been reactivated?

Comment: I would assume that is what I am looking for

Comment: Both of the other two answers seem to mean "was closed, and then later reactivated at some point" (even if closed again later)

Comment: No just reactivated at least once. but not having latest updated status of closed

Comment: "Reactivated as its status but not having the most recent record for that ID as a closed status" can you check my test again and tell me are there any other scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all reactivated projects and check is it have a closed status.

Its not optimized but i think it works.

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM project as p1
WHERE Status = "Reactivated"
AND ProjectID NOT IN (SELECT ProjectID FROM project AS p2 WHERE Status = "Closed" AND p2.Updatedate > p1.UpdateDate)
```

## Tests

```
|-ProjectID-|-UpdateDate-|-   Status    -|
|-    1    -|-2011-11-15-|- Closed      -|
|-    1    -|-2011-11-16-|- Reactivated -|
|-    1    -|-2011-11-17-|- Opened      -|
|-    2    -|-2011-11-15-|- Reactivated -|
|-    2    -|-2011-11-16-|- Closed      -|
|-    2    -|-2011-11-17-|- Reactivated -|
|-    3    -|-2011-11-15-|- Closed      -|
|-    3    -|-2011-11-16-|- Reactivated -|
|-    3    -|-2011-11-17-|- Closed      -|
```

### Result

```
|-ProjectID-|-UpdateDate-|-   Status    -|
|-    1    -|-2011-11-16-|- Reactivated -|
|-    2    -|-2011-11-17-|- Reactivated -|
```

Comment: This will show things that are closed, reactivated, then closed, and it will not show things that are reactivated, closed, then opened.

Comment: "closed, reactivated, then opened" i think this need to show,
"reactivated, closed, then opened" will not show becouse asker dont want it. in his logic or ticket logic, you cant active a closed ticket, you can reactivate a closed ticket

Comment: Sorry, I quickly changed it to "closed, reactivated then closed"

Comment: McKay, i added some test check it please

Comment: I am selecting your answer as the right one since it was the one I ended up using. I gave McKay an upvote since his was also good and helped me explain better what I wanted thanks all for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is "most recent is reactivated"

```
select
    *
  from
    Project P -- I'm guessing at this table name
    join
    (select MAX(UpdateDate) lastUpdate, ProjectId from Project group by ProjectId) L on L.ProjectId = P.ProjectId AND L.lastUpdate = P.UpdateDate        
  where 
    Status = 'Reactivated'
```

This is "most recent is not closed, but has at some point been reactivated" which is lieterally what you asked for

```
select distinct  -- there may be more than one "reactivated" per project
    R.ProjectId
  from
    Project R join        
    (select
        P.ProjectId
      from
        Project P join
        (select
            MAX(InsertDate) InsertDate,
            ProjectId
          from
            Project 
          group by
            ProjectId) MostRecent M on P.InsertDate = M.InsertDate and P.ProjectId = M.ProjectId
      where
        Status <> 'Closed') O on O.ProjectId = R.ProjectId
  where
    Status = 'Reactivated'
```

Comment: its possible that after being reactivated that it can be switched to either pending or active meaning that it is still reactivated

Comment: So you want anything that has ever been reactivated?

Comment: look at my updates in my question. reactivated in the history but not the latest entry of update being a closed status

Comment: @LaurenceBurke I just added that one as a secondary option.

Comment: yeah its giving me problems trying to rework it and its giving me errors

Comment: ambigiuos projectid  above your p table and then when I put p.projectid it says incorrect syntax near where clause at the bottom

Comment: Ok looks good for now im going to put more test data in it and make sure it works correctly. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution (with sp bonus ) )

```
CREATE PROC sp_GetReactivatedProjects
AS
    SELECT RA.ProjectID 
    FROM 
        (SELECT ProjectID, max(UpdateDate) as RaDate
         FROM Project 
         WHERE Status = 'Reactivated'
         GROUP BY ProjectID) RA
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT ProjectID, max(UpdateDate) as ClDate
         FROM Project 
         WHERE Status = 'Closed'
         GROUP BY ProjectID) Cl
    ON RA.ProjectId = Cl.ProjectID
    WHERE raDate > ClDate or ClDate is null
```

Hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Not exists to the rescue!

```
-- generate some data
DROP TABLE tmp.projects;
CREATE TABLE tmp.projects
    ( projectid INTEGER NOT NULL
    , updatedate DATE NOT NULL
    , status varchar
    , PRIMARY KEY (projectid,updatedate)
    );
INSERT INTO tmp.projects VALUES
  (    1    , '2011-11-15' , 'Closed' )
, (    1    , '2011-11-16' , 'Reactivated' )
, (    1    , '2011-11-17' , 'Opened' )
, (    2    , '2011-11-15' , 'Reactivated' )
, (    2    , '2011-11-16' , 'Closed' )
, (    2    , '2011-11-17' , 'Reactivated' )
, (    3    , '2011-11-15' , 'Closed' )
, (    3    , '2011-11-16' , 'Reactivated' )
, (    3    , '2011-11-17' , 'Closed' )
    ;

SET search_path='tmp';

SELECT * FROM projects p1;

SELECT * FROM projects p1
WHERE status = 'Reactivated'
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
    FROM projects nx
    WHERE nx.projectid = p1.projectid
    AND nx.updatedate > p1.updatedate
    AND nx.status IN ( 'Closed' , 'Reactivated' )
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM projects zlast
        WHERE zlast.projectid = nx.projectid
        AND zlast.updatedate > nx.updatedate
        )   
    );
```

The result:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 9
SET
 projectid | updatedate |   status    
-----------+------------+-------------
         1 | 2011-11-15 | Closed
         1 | 2011-11-16 | Reactivated
         1 | 2011-11-17 | Opened
         2 | 2011-11-15 | Reactivated
         2 | 2011-11-16 | Closed
         2 | 2011-11-17 | Reactivated
         3 | 2011-11-15 | Closed
         3 | 2011-11-16 | Reactivated
         3 | 2011-11-17 | Closed
(9 rows)

 projectid | updatedate |   status    
-----------+------------+-------------
         1 | 2011-11-16 | Reactivated
         2 | 2011-11-17 | Reactivated
(2 rows)
```

There might be a recursive CTE possible ;-)